# Pass Row ID to a custom component in MUI Datagrid Pro

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui, mui-datatable

I am trying to add an indeterminate state to row checkboxes based on selection status of other checkboxes inside a detail panel. To do this I am creating a custom checkbox component and doing some logic to see if indeterminate should be true, the only problem is the checkbox needs access to the row id it is associated with to do that check. Thus far I've found nothing to pass anything other than the given CheckboxProps given by MUI, which contains no row information. There is something called componentsProps where I can pass other props to a component, but I've yet to find a way to pass the particular row id to its associated checkbox. Does anyone know of a solution to this?

```
.
.
.
const customCheckbox = (props: CheckboxProps) => {
    return <Checkbox {...props} indeterminate={someArray.includes(theRowIdThisCheckboxIsUsedIn)} />
};

<DataGridPro
        {...data}
        components={{
          BaseCheckbox: customCheckbox,
        }}

/>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi when you use custom checkbox component you cant use `onSelectionModelChange` to give you rows id you must write their logic too